# How to convince longtable to do a page break earlier

Tags: page-breaking, longtable

using the longtable package to typeset page spanning tables, I run into a nasty behaviour: only a dummy table head and the caption are put on the following page. The contents of the table is extracted from program sources. I don't have much influence here.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,DIV10,BCOR1.5cm]{scrbook}
\usepackage{longtable}
\newlength{\tablcol}
\setlength{\tablcol}{4.7cm}
\newlength{\tabrcol}
\setlength{\tabrcol}{8.1cm}
\itemsep0ex plus0.2ex
%
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{p{\tablcol}p{\tabrcol}}%
%
\hline \multicolumn{1}{l}{{\bfseries Feld}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{{\bfseries Beschreibung}}\\ \hline
\endfirsthead
%
\hline \multicolumn{2}{l}%
{{\small\slshape Fortsetzung der vorherigen Seite}}\\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{l}{{\bfseries Feld}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{{\bfseries Beschreibung}}\\ \hline
\endhead
%
\hline \multicolumn{2}{l}%
{{\small\slshape Fortsetzung auf der n\"achsten Seite}}\\ \hline
\endfoot
%
\hline
\caption[show user output]{Beschreibung der Output-Struktur des show user Statements}
\endlastfoot
%
\label{tucshowxuser}%
{\scshape id} & Die Nummer des Repository Objektes \\
{\scshape name} & Der Name des Objektes \\
{\scshape creator} & Name des Benutzers der dieses Objekt angelegt hat \\
{\scshape create\_time} & Datum und Uhrzeit der Erstellung \\
{\scshape changer} & Name des Benutzers der dieses Objekt zuletzt ge\"andert hat \\
{\scshape change\_time} & Datum und Uhrzeit der letzten \"Anderung \\
{\scshape privs} & Zeichenkette die K\"urzel f\"ur die Benutzerrechte auf dieses Objekt enth\"alt \\
{\scshape commenttype} & Typ des Kommentars \\
{\scshape comment} & Kommentar zum Objekt, wenn vorhanden \\
{\scshape id} & Die Nummer des Repository Objektes \\
{\scshape name} & Der Name des Objektes \\
{\scshape creator} & Name des Benutzers der dieses Objekt angelegt hat \\
{\scshape create\_time} & Datum und Uhrzeit der Erstellung \\
{\scshape changer} & Name des Benutzers der dieses Objekt zuletzt ge\"andert hat \\
{\scshape change\_time} & Datum und Uhrzeit der letzten \"Anderung \\
{\scshape privs} & Zeichenkette die K\"urzel f\"ur die Benutzerrechte auf dieses Objekt enth\"alt \\
{\scshape commenttype} & Typ des Kommentars \\
{\scshape comment} & Kommentar zum Objekt, wenn vorhanden \\
{\scshape id} & Die Nummer des Repository Objektes \\
{\scshape name} & Der Name des Objektes \\
{\scshape creator} & Name des Benutzers der dieses Objekt angelegt hat \\
{\scshape create\_time} & Datum und Uhrzeit der Erstellung \\
{\scshape changer} & Name des Benutzers der dieses Objekt zuletzt ge\"andert hat \\
{\scshape change\_time} & Datum und Uhrzeit der letzten \"Anderung \\
{\scshape privs} & Zeichenkette die K\"urzel f\"ur die Benutzerrechte auf dieses Objekt enth\"alt \\
{\scshape commenttype} & Typ des Kommentars \\
{\scshape comment} & Kommentar zum Objekt, wenn vorhanden \\
{\scshape id} & Die Nummer des Repository Objektes \\
{\scshape name} & Der Name des Objektes \\
{\scshape creator} & Name des Benutzers der dieses Objekt angelegt hat \\
{\scshape create\_time} & Datum und Uhrzeit der Erstellung \\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

The problem is that I don't find a method to force a page break earlier. A page that isn't filled entirely, followed by a page with the last part of a table is better than this.

I tried to add "\needspace{*someLength*}" at the beginning or end of the rows, but that doesn't work either. It simply makes the rows *someLength* high instead of forcing a page break if there's no more than *someLength* room left on the page.

I'd be more than grateful for some solution or even a good hint.

TIA

Comment: `longtable` has a `\pagebreak` command defined.

Comment: Why do you put the caption in the last foot? That's an odd place for a tabular caption.

Comment: @Troy I know, but the program that generates the table from the sources has no idea where on the page it is. A "\pagebreak" after each line isn't exactly what I am targeting at.

Comment: @Ronald That wasn't clear in your question. In that case, a description of how your program outputs this data is required here, I would imagine.

Comment: The bottom caption might be an odd place, but all the captions in the document are bottom captions.

Comment: @Troy simple question, long answer. The document is actually a command language description. The tables describe the output of show and list commands. The program that generates the TeX source reads the parser source code and generates syntax diagrams. Then it fetches TeX snippets that describe the command and the options. If the command replies with data, the data structure is extracted again from the source code and rendered into a longtable. As a result, most of the document is generated from the source code. Probably like tangle and weave; suits here :-)

Comment: If everything in the first column should be scshape, why don't you just tell the column to do that automatically, saves a lot of typing, see the array package (not sure it longtable already loads it)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can force a page break using `\pagebreak`

```
\pagebreak
{\scshape creator} & Name des Benutzers der dieses Objekt angelegt hat \\
{\scshape create\_time} & Datum und Uhrzeit der Erstellung
\end{longtable}
```

for example will push two rows to the last page.

If you want to ensure that two rows always stay with the caption without having to add `\pagebreak` then put the final two rows of the table into the `\endlastfoot` area, as described in the `longtable` documentation.