# Two pages threeparttable tabularx extension

Tags: tables

It seems like I have a problem with the threeparttable by using tabularx.
The table notes do not span over two pages.

Do you have any idea how I can solve this issue?

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{book}  

\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{bigints}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabularx, caption}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\centering}m{#1}}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{footnote}
\makesavenoteenv{tabular}
\makesavenoteenv{table}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{longtable}


\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=3.5cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t!]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
\centering{
                \caption{holderholderholderholderholderholderholderholderholderholderholderholderholderholderholderholder.}
    \label{ProCons_CSM_DTM_SSM}
    \begin{threeparttable}
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X||*{3}{Cc|}}
            \hline
            & \multicolumn{3}{Cc|}{\textbf{Hooooolder}} \\
            \textbf{holder} & holder & holder & holder \\
            \hline \hline
            holder & holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} no \tnote{1} \\
            \hline          
            holder holder holder holder holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder\\       
            \hline
            \textbf{holder} & holder & holder & holder \\
            \hline 
            holder & holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} no \tnote{2} \\
            \hline          
            holder holder holder holder holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder\\                       
            \hline  
            holder & holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} no \tnote{3} \\
            \hline          
            holder holder holder holder holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder holder\\        
            \hline
            \textbf{holder} & holder & holder & holder \\
            \hline
            holder & holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} no \tnote{4} \\
            \hline          
            holder holder holder holder holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder\\                       
            \hline
            holder & holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} no \tnote{5} \\
            \hline          
            holder holder holder holder holder & holder holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder\\        
            \hline
            \textbf{holder} & holder & holder & holder \\
            \hline 
            holder & holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} no \tnote{6} \\
            \hline          
            holder holder holder holder holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder holder holder holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder\\                      
            \hline
            holder & holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} no \tnote{7} \\
            \hline          
            holder holder holder holder holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder\\       
            \hline
            \textbf{holder} & holder & holder & holder \\
            \hline 
            holder & holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} no \tnote{8} \\
            \hline          
            holder holder holder holder holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder\\                       
            \hline  
            holder & holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} no \tnote{1} \\
            \hline          
            holder holder holder holder holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder\\       
            \hline
            \textbf{holder} & holder & holder & holder \\
            \hline \hline
            holder & holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} no \tnote{12} \\
            \hline          
            holder holder holder holder holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder\\                       
            \hline                                                                      
        \end{tabularx}
        \begin{tablenotes}
            \setlength\labelsep{4pt}
            \footnotesize   
            \item \textbf{Table Notes:}
            \item[1] textetxt. 
            \item[2] textetxt. 
            \item[3] textetxttextetxttextetxttextetxttextetxttextetx ttextetxt textetxt textetxttextetxttex tetxttextetxttextetxttextetxt textetxttextetxt textetxt.
            \item[4] textetxt.
            \item[5] textetxt. 
            \item[6] textetxt.
            \item[7] textetxt.
            \item[8] textetxt.  
            \item[9] textetxt.
            \item[10] textetxt. 
            \item[11] textetxt.                     
            \item[12] textetxt.
        \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here comes the second issue if I use the second table:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{book}

\usepackage[a4paper,
hmargin={2.5cm},
top=2.5cm,
bottom=3.5cm]{geometry}


%\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{array, ltablex, threeparttablex}
%\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
%\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
%
%%-------------------------------- show page layout, only for test
%\usepackage{showframe}
%\usepackage{afterpage}
%\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
%\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

%------------------------------ Setting for additional table
\usepackage{bigints}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{tabularx, caption}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\centering}m{#1}}


\begin{document}

%   \afterpage{\clearpage
%       \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}%
%       \captionsetup{position=top}%
%       \captionof{table}{holder holder holder holder holder holder holder     holder holder holder holder holder holder holder holder holder.}
%       \label{ProCons_CSM_DTM_SSM}%
%       \let\TPToverlap=\TPTrlap
%       \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X||*{3}{C|}}
%           \hline
%           & \multicolumn{3}{C|}{\textbf{Hooooolder}} \\
%           \textbf{holder} & holder & holder & holder \\
%           \hline \hline
%           holder & holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} no \tnote{1} \\
%           \hline          
%           holder holder holder holder holder & holder &     \cellcolor{green!25} holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder\\       
%           \hline
%           \textbf{holder} & holder & holder & holder \\
%           \hline 
%           holder & holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} no \tnote{2} \\
%           \hline          
%           holder holder holder holder holder & holder &     \cellcolor{green!25} holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder\\                       
%           \hline  
%           holder & holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} no \tnote{3} \\
%           \hline          
%           holder holder holder holder holder & holder &     \cellcolor{green!25} holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder holder\\        
%           \hline
%           \textbf{holder} & holder & holder & holder \\
%           \hline
%           holder & holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} no \tnote{4} \\
%           \hline          
%           holder holder holder holder holder & holder &     \cellcolor{green!25} holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder\\                       
%           \hline
%           holder & holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} no \tnote{5} \\
%           \hline          
%           holder holder holder holder holder & holder holder &     \cellcolor{green!25} holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder\\        
%           \hline
%           \textbf{holder} & holder & holder & holder \\
%           \hline 
%           holder & holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} no \tnote{6} \\
%           \hline          
%           holder holder holder holder holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder holder holder holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder\\                      
%           \hline
%           holder & holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} no \tnote{7} \\
%           \hline          
%           holder holder holder holder holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder\\       
%           \hline
%           \textbf{holder} & holder & holder & holder \\
%           \hline 
%           holder & holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} no \tnote{8} \\
%           \hline          
%           holder holder holder holder holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder\\                       
%           \hline  
%           holder & holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} no \tnote{1} \\
%           \hline          
%           holder holder holder holder holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder\\       
%           \hline
%           \textbf{holder} & holder & holder & holder \\
%           \hline \hline
%           holder & holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} no \tnote{12} \\
%           \hline          
%           holder holder holder holder holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder\\                       
%           \hline
%       \end{tabularx}
%       \begin{ThreePartTable}
%           \begin{tablenotes}
%               \setlength\labelsep{4pt}
%               \footnotesize   
%               \item \textbf{Table Notes:}
%               \item[1] textetxt. 
%               \item[2] textetxt. 
%               \item[3] textetxttextetxttextetxttextetxttextetxttextetx ttextetxt textetxt textetxttextetxttex tetxttextetxttextetxttextetxt textetxttextetxt textetxt.
%               \item[4] textetxt.
%               \item[5] textetxt. 
%               \item[6] textetxt.
%               \item[7] textetxt.
%               \item[8] textetxt.  
%               \item[9] textetxt.
%               \item[10] textetxt. 
%               \item[11] textetxt.                     
%               \item[12] textetxt.
%           \end{tablenotes}
%       \end{ThreePartTable}%
%   }% end of \afterpage

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Hodor Table}
\setlength\extrarowheight{0.8pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X||*{6}{Cc|}}
    \hline
    Hodor & Hodor & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Hodor Hodor}& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Hodor} & Hodor Hodor \\
    \cline{2-6}
    & $\boldsymbol{erg}$ &$\boldsymbol{gg}$ & $\boldsymbol{hh}$ &     $\boldsymbol{4_111}$ & {$\boldsymbol{ns}$} & {Hodor Hodor} \\
    \cline{1-7}
    \strut Hodor, \emph{two} HodorHodor & $\begin{bmatrix} JJ_{cc} \end{bmatrix}$ & $\begin{bmatrix} sdW_{11} \\ g_{21} \end{bmatrix}$ & $\begin{bmatrix} s_{11} \\ g_{21} \end{bmatrix}$ & $\begin{bmatrix} sd_{12} \\ wer_{22} \end{bmatrix}$ & $\begin{bmatrix} 0 \end{bmatrix}$ & d \\
    \hline
    \strut Hodor, \emph{two} HodorHodor &  $\begin{bmatrix} zi_{dfg} \\ z_{v} \end{bmatrix}$ &$\begin{bmatrix} W_{11} & ert_{21} \\ cv_{31} & dfg_{41} \end{bmatrix}$ & $\begin{bmatrix} hB_{11} \\ ert_{21} \end{bmatrix}$ & $\begin{bmatrix} f_{12} \\ dfg_{22} \end{bmatrix}$ & $\begin{bmatrix} 0 \end{bmatrix}$ & f \\
    \hline
    \strut Hodor, \emph{three} HodorHodor &  $\begin{bmatrix} zi_{f} \\ z_{d} \end{bmatrix}$ &$\begin{bmatrix} W_{11} & W_{21} \\ hvgj_{31} & ee_{41} \\ ddd_{51} & zzz_{61} \end{bmatrix}$ & $\begin{bmatrix} B_{11} \\ B_{21} \\ B_{31} \end{bmatrix}$ & $\begin{bmatrix} 42_{12} \\ 12_{22} \\ W_{32} \end{bmatrix}$ &     $\begin{bmatrix} 0 \end{bmatrix}$ & g \\
    \hline      
\end{tabularx}
\label{nn-net_verror}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, the infamous non-specific Thesis class!  If I could run your code I would give an answer.  The short version is, floats don't break across pages.  Use \afterpage and \captionof{table} instead.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I modified the code. Hope it will work now. I tried \afterpage but the item numbers disappeared on the next page...

Comment: **off-topics**: (i) you have defined 7 column but use only 4, (ii) for multi page `tabularx` you should consider `ltablex` and `threeparttablex` packages ...  **on-topic**: try to force table break before last row that last row and `\tnotes{...}` will move to next page (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/358435/how-to-convince-longtable-to-do-a-page-break-earlier)

Comment: @Zarko a force will probably not help in the OPs MWE, it is inside a float.

Comment: you have right, i should mentioned that "on-topic" part of my comment has sense if table is not in float environment ...

Comment: **addendum** to my previous comment: suggestion in "on-topic" part has sense only, if your table *is not* in float environment. also see if it is acceptable for you to change `tablenotes` format to `\begin{tablenotes}[para, flushleft] `

Comment: @Zarko, the \begin{tablenotes}[para, flushleft] helps me not, unfortunately, because the item text is too long. Some items will be still on the second page.

Comment: @Zeit, do you consider other suggestion (remove `table` environment, number of columns etc) and test, it they help?

Comment: @Zarko, yes I tried it. At least to my best skills. I am not very into Latex. Maybe you can copy the code above and test it on your system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a similar problem using  `ThreePartTable` and `longtable` (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/359903/i-have-table-with-long-notes-in-the-longtable-and-threeparttable-environment-h/359916?s=2%7C29.2666#359916)),  The solution was to use `\footnotemark` instead of `\tnote` and use `ThreePartTable` ONLY for the notes.

I have since discovered how to get `\tnote` to function outside the `ThreePartTable` environment, which will save some editing.

It should be noted that `\afterpage` is being used simply to emulate a [tp] table. It also puts the contents into a group (local definitions). `\clearpage` makes sure that the tables appear in the correct order.

BTW, it has been a while since I read *Game of Thrones*, but I believe his name was spelled "Hodor".

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,
            hmargin={2.5cm},
            top=2.5cm,
            bottom=3.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array, ltablex, threeparttablex}
    \newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
    \setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}

%-------------------------------- show page layout, only for test
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\afterpage{\clearpage
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}%
    \captionsetup{position=top}%
    \captionof{table}{holder holder holder holder holder holder holder holder holder holder holder holder holder holder holder holder.}
    \label{ProCons_CSM_DTM_SSM}%
    \let\TPToverlap=\TPTrlap
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X||*{3}{C|}}
            \hline
            & \multicolumn{3}{C|}{\textbf{Hooooolder}} \\
            \textbf{holder} & holder & holder & holder \\
            \hline \hline
            holder & holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} no \tnote{1} \\
            \hline          
            holder holder holder holder holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder\\       
            \hline
            \textbf{holder} & holder & holder & holder \\
            \hline 
            holder & holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} no \tnote{2} \\
            \hline          
            holder holder holder holder holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder\\                       
            \hline  
            holder & holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} no \tnote{3} \\
            \hline          
            holder holder holder holder holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder holder\\        
            \hline
            \textbf{holder} & holder & holder & holder \\
            \hline
            holder & holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} no \tnote{4} \\
            \hline          
            holder holder holder holder holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder\\                       
            \hline
            holder & holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} no \tnote{5} \\
            \hline          
            holder holder holder holder holder & holder holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder\\        
            \hline
            \textbf{holder} & holder & holder & holder \\
            \hline 
            holder & holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} no \tnote{6} \\
            \hline          
            holder holder holder holder holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder holder holder holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder\\                      
            \hline
            holder & holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} no \tnote{7} \\
            \hline          
            holder holder holder holder holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder\\       
            \hline
            \textbf{holder} & holder & holder & holder \\
            \hline 
            holder & holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} no \tnote{8} \\
            \hline          
            holder holder holder holder holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder\\                       
            \hline  
            holder & holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} no \tnote{1} \\
            \hline          
            holder holder holder holder holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder\\       
            \hline
            \textbf{holder} & holder & holder & holder \\
            \hline \hline
            holder & holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} no \tnote{12} \\
            \hline          
            holder holder holder holder holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder\\                       
            \hline
       \end{tabularx}
    \begin{ThreePartTable}
       \begin{tablenotes}
            \setlength\labelsep{4pt}
            \footnotesize   
            \item \textbf{Table Notes:}
            \item[1] textetxt. 
            \item[2] textetxt. 
            \item[3] textetxttextetxttextetxttextetxttextetxttextetx ttextetxt textetxt textetxttextetxttex tetxttextetxttextetxttextetxt textetxttextetxt textetxt.
            \item[4] textetxt.
            \item[5] textetxt. 
            \item[6] textetxt.
            \item[7] textetxt.
            \item[8] textetxt.  
            \item[9] textetxt.
            \item[10] textetxt. 
            \item[11] textetxt.                     
            \item[12] textetxt.
        \end{tablenotes}
    \end{ThreePartTable}%
}% end of \afterpage
\end{document}
```

---

Solution for revised MWE.  I had to replace `ltablex` with `longtable` and compute the column widths "manually."  I replaced `cellspace` by using a new column type.

Note: Putting braces around the matrices isn't needed, but was done as an experiment earlier.  I just didn't want to take the effort to remove them again.

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{book}

\usepackage[a4paper,
hmargin={2.5cm},
top=2.5cm,
bottom=3.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bigints}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{afterpage}

%------------------------------ Setting for additional table
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\centering}m{#1}}

%% ---------------------------- cellspace replacement (column a only)
\newcommand{\cell}[1]% #1 = text
{\bgroup
  \sbox0{#1}\rule[\dimexpr-\dp0-\fboxsep]{0pt}{\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0+2\fboxsep}\usebox0%
\egroup}
\usepackage{collcell}
\newcolumntype{a}{>{\collectcell\cell}c<{\endcollectcell}}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\newlength{\Xcolumn}
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
%
%%-------------------------------- show page layout, only for test
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%


\begin{document}

   \afterpage{\clearpage
       \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}%
       \let\TPToverlap=\TPTrlap
       \setlength{\Xcolumn}{\dimexpr \textwidth -8\tabcolsep -6\arrayrulewidth-\doublerulesep}% compute width of X column
       \divide\Xcolumn by 4
       \begin{longtable}{|m{\Xcolumn}||*3{C{\Xcolumn}|}}
           \caption{holder holder holder holder holder holder holder     holder holder holder holder holder holder holder holder holder.}%
           \label{ProCons_CSM_DTM_SSM}
           \endfirsthead
           \hline
           & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{Hooooolder}} \\
           \cline{2-4}
           \textbf{holder} & holder & holder & holder \\
           \hline \hline
           holder & holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} no \tnote{1} \\
           \hline          
           holder holder holder holder holder & holder &     \cellcolor{green!25} holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder\\       
           \hline
           \textbf{holder} & holder & holder & holder \\
           \hline 
           holder & holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} no \tnote{2} \\
           \hline          
           holder holder holder holder holder & holder &     \cellcolor{green!25} holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder\\                       
           \hline  
           holder & holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} no \tnote{3} \\
           \hline          
           holder holder holder holder holder & holder &     \cellcolor{green!25} holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder holder\\        
           \hline
           \textbf{holder} & holder & holder & holder \\
           \hline
           holder & holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} no \tnote{4} \\
           \hline          
           holder holder holder holder holder & holder &     \cellcolor{green!25} holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder\\                       
           \hline
           holder & holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} no \tnote{5} \\
           \hline          
           holder holder holder holder holder & holder holder &     \cellcolor{green!25} holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder\\        
           \hline
           \textbf{holder} & holder & holder & holder \\
           \hline 
           holder & holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} no \tnote{6} \\
           \hline          
           holder holder holder holder holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder holder holder holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder\\                      
           \hline
           holder & holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} no \tnote{7} \\
           \hline          
           holder holder holder holder holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder\\       
           \hline
           \textbf{holder} & holder & holder & holder \\
           \hline 
           holder & holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} no \tnote{8} \\
           \hline          
           holder holder holder holder holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder\\                       
           \hline  
           holder & holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} no \tnote{1} \\
           \hline          
           holder holder holder holder holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder\\       
           \hline
           \textbf{holder} & holder & holder & holder \\
           \hline \hline
           holder & holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} no \tnote{12} \\
           \hline          
           holder holder holder holder holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder\\                       
           \hline
       \end{longtable}
       \begin{ThreePartTable}
           \begin{tablenotes}
               \setlength\labelsep{4pt}
               \footnotesize   
               \item \textbf{Table Notes:}
               \item[1] textetxt. 
               \item[2] textetxt. 
               \item[3] textetxttextetxttextetxttextetxttextetxttextetx ttextetxt textetxt textetxttextetxttex tetxttextetxttextetxttextetxt textetxttextetxt textetxt.
               \item[4] textetxt.
               \item[5] textetxt. 
               \item[6] textetxt.
               \item[7] textetxt.
               \item[8] textetxt.  
               \item[9] textetxt.
               \item[10] textetxt. 
               \item[11] textetxt.                     
               \item[12] textetxt.
           \end{tablenotes}
       \end{ThreePartTable}
   }% end of \afterpage

\begin{table}[h]
\setlength\extrarowheight{0.8pt}%
  \caption{Hodor Table}\label{nn-net_verror}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X||*6{a|}}
    \hline
    Hodor & Hodor & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Hodor Hodor}& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Hodor} & Hodor Hodor \\
    \cline{2-6}
    & $\boldsymbol{erg}$ &$\boldsymbol{gg}$ & $\boldsymbol{hh}$ & $\boldsymbol{4_111}$ & {$\boldsymbol{ns}$} & {Hodor Hodor} \\
    \hline
    \strut Hodor, \emph{two} HodorHodor & 
      {$\begin{bmatrix} JJ_{cc} \end{bmatrix}$} & 
      {$\begin{bmatrix} sdW_{11} \\ g_{21} \end{bmatrix}$} & 
      {$\begin{bmatrix} s_{11} \\ g_{21} \end{bmatrix}$} & 
      {$\begin{bmatrix} sd_{12} \\ wer_{22} \end{bmatrix}$} & 
      {$\begin{bmatrix} 0 \end{bmatrix}$} & 
      d \\
    \hline
    \strut Hodor, \emph{two} HodorHodor &  
      {$\begin{bmatrix} zi_{dfg} \\ z_{v} \end{bmatrix}$} &
      {$\begin{bmatrix} W_{11} & ert_{21} \\ cv_{31} & dfg_{41} \end{bmatrix}$} &
      {$\begin{bmatrix} hB_{11} \\ ert_{21} \end{bmatrix}$} & 
      {$\begin{bmatrix} f_{12} \\ dfg_{22} \end{bmatrix}$} &
      {$\begin{bmatrix} 0 \end{bmatrix}$} &
      f \\
    \hline
    \strut Hodor, \emph{three} HodorHodor &
      {$\begin{bmatrix} zi_{f} \\ z_{d} \end{bmatrix}$} &
      {$\begin{bmatrix} W_{11} & W_{21} \\ hvgj_{31} & ee_{41} \\ ddd_{51} & zzz_{61} \end{bmatrix}$} &
      {$\begin{bmatrix} B_{11} \\ B_{21} \\ B_{31} \end{bmatrix}$} & 
      {$\begin{bmatrix} 42_{12} \\ 12_{22} \\ W_{32} \end{bmatrix}$} &
      {$\begin{bmatrix} 0 \end{bmatrix}$} & 
      g \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\ref{nn-net_verror}

\ref{ProCons_CSM_DTM_SSM}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, that is a nice solution. Unfortunately I have some issues now because of some other settings I used for other tables:

\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\centering}m{#1}}

Can you somehow consider this so that I can use your code and the old settings?

Ohhh Hodor :) Hold the door ;)

Comment: Can you revise your MWE to show the problem?

Comment: Please find the modified code above. I used your code as a reference and added the table which produces the problem.

Comment: Aside from using Cc where you should use c (which works when C is not defined), the incompatibility appears to be with siunitx.  That plus the table counter is being incremented twice.

Comment: When loading ltablex, the \caption goes inside tabularx, and table is optional (single page tables only).

Comment: Thank you very much for your support! If there is no standard way to fix this, I will better use two instead of one table.

Comment: I was able to fix the conflicts by replacing ltablex with longtable and replacing cellspace (which didn't seem to be working anyway) with a new column type.

Answer (score 1):

see if the following redesign of your table, considering my comments above, works for you:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,
            hmargin={2.5cm},
            top=2.5cm,
            bottom=3.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array, ltablex, threeparttablex}
    \newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
    \setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}

%-------------------------------- show page layout, only for test
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}

\begin{ThreePartTable}
    \begin{TableNotes}[flushleft]\footnotesize
\item \textbf{Table Notes:}
\item[1] textetxt.
\item[2] textetxt.
\item[3] textetxttextetxttextetxttextetxttextetxttextetx ttextetxt textetxt textetxttextetxttex tetxttextetxttextetxttextetxt textetxttextetxt textetxt.
\item[4] textetxt.
\item[5] textetxt.
\item[6] textetxt.
\item[7] textetxt.
\item[8] textetxt.
\item[9] textetxt.
\item[10] textetxt.
\item[11] textetxt.
\item[12] textetxt.
    \end{TableNotes}
%
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| X || c | C | c | }
\caption{holder holder holder holder holder holder holder holder holder holder holder holder holder holder holder holder.}
\label{ProCons_CSM_DTM_SSM}                                                 \\
    \hline
                &   \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{Hooooolder}}                \\
    \cline{2-4}
\textbf{holder} &   holder  &   holder  &   holder                          \\
    \hline\hline
\endfirsthead
    \hline
                &   \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{Hooooolder}}                \\
    \cline{2-4}
\textbf{holder} &   holder  &   holder  &   holder                          \\
    \hline\hline
\endhead
    \hline
\insertTableNotes\medskip\\
    \hline
\multicolumn{4}{r}{\textit{Continue on the next page}}                     \\
\endfoot
    \hline
\insertTableNotes
\endlastfoot
% table content
holder          &   holder  &   holder  & \cellcolor{green!25} no           \\
holder & holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} no \tnote{1} \\
    \hline
holder holder holder holder holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder\\
    \hline
\textbf{holder} & holder & holder & holder \\
    \hline
holder & holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} no \tnote{2} \\
    \hline
holder holder holder holder holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder\\
    \hline
holder & holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} no \tnote{3} \\
    \hline
holder holder holder holder holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder holder\\
    \hline
\textbf{holder} & holder & holder & holder \\
    \hline
holder & holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} no \tnote{4} \\
    \hline
holder holder holder holder holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder\\
    \hline
holder & holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} no \tnote{5} \\
    \hline
holder holder holder holder holder & holder holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder\\
    \hline
\textbf{holder} & holder & holder & holder \\
    \hline
holder & holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} no \tnote{6} \\
    \hline
holder holder holder holder holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder holder holder holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder\\
    \hline
holder & holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} no \tnote{7} \\
    \hline
holder holder holder holder holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder\\
    \hline
\textbf{holder} & holder & holder & holder \\
    \hline
holder & holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} no \tnote{8} \\
    \hline
holder holder holder holder holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder\\
    \hline
holder & holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} no \tnote{1} \\
    \hline
holder holder holder holder holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder\\
    \hline
\textbf{holder} & holder & holder & holder \\
    \hline \hline
holder & holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} no \tnote{12} \\
    \hline
holder holder holder holder holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder\\
\end{tabularx}
    \end{ThreePartTable}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your good answer. But I was more looking for something which only shifts the hidden notes to the second page. Using your solution I have all the table notes on both pages, if I understand correctly.