# smart division of tablenotes at long table between pages

Tags: longtable, tablenotes

as background see my answer on [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/399937/two-pages-threeparttable-tabularx-extension).

i wonder, if it is possible that `tablenotes` be (automatically) split between pages on the way, that on each pages are present only items which are used on this pages. for given example example that on the first page `tablenotes` contain only items from 1 to 7 and on second package only items 1, 8 and 12.

for start i would be happy if it is possible to define two `tablenotes` and use the first one on the first table page and the second on the second page containing `longtable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the easy solution with many `TableNotes`.

Here I rewrote the `TableNotes` environment and `\insertTableNotes` to take an additional mandatory argument to name the table notes. Caution, there is no check, if a table note with a specific name (already) exists.

You can have as many table notes as you want (see second page of example). But of course there are only two feet for a `longtable`, so you can only have two differnt sets of notes. (If I could figure out, how to change a foot mid table, then there may be a chance to automate the notes. But so far, no luck.)

The result:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,
            hmargin={2.5cm},
            top=2.5cm,
            bottom=3.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array, ltablex, threeparttablex}
    \newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
    \setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}

%-------------------------------- show page layout, only for test
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\makeatletter
% rewritten macros from threeparttablex
\renewenvironment{TableNotes}[2][]{%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname TPTL@optarg@#2\endcsname{#1}%
  \expandafter\def\csname TPTL@collector@#2\endcsname##1{%
      \expandafter\long\expandafter\gdef\csname TPTL@body@#2\endcsname{##1}}%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname TPTL@body@#2\endcsname{}%
  \expandafter\Collect@Body\csname TPTL@collector@#2\endcsname}{}
% original code
%%%%\newenvironment{TableNotes}[1][]{
%%%%  \gdef\TPTL@optarg{#1}%
%%%%  \Collect@Body\TPTL@collector}{}
%%%%\newcommand\TPTL@collector[1]{%
%%%%  \long\gdef\TPTL@body{#1}}
%%%%% the macro used to store the tablenotes contents
%%%%\gdef\TPTL@body{}
% rewritten macros from threeparttablex
% added argument
\renewcommand\insertTableNotes[1]{%
  % first we need to know the width of the longtable, remember that it
  % will only settle after a few compilations
  \noalign{\begingroup
  \setlength\TPTL@width{0pt}
  \renewcommand\LT@entry[2]{\global\advance\TPTL@width by ##2}
  \@nameuse{LT@\romannumeral\c@LT@tables}
  \ifdim\TPTL@width<\TPTminimum\relax\global\TPTL@width=\TPTminimum\fi
  \endgroup}
  % then add the table notes inside a \parbox of the required width
  \multicolumn{\LT@cols}{c}{%
    \makebox[0pt][c]{%
      \parbox{\TPTL@width}{%
        \let\TPT@hsize\@empty% otherwise the width is not reset
                             % correctly as \TPT@hsize messes with 
                             % \@parboxrestore
        \let\TPToverlap\relax%
        % added
        \expandafter\let\expandafter\TPTL@optarg\csname TPTL@optarg@#1\endcsname
        \begin{tablenotes}[\TPTL@optarg]%
          \TPTL@font%
          % changed
          \csname TPTL@body@#1\endcsname
          % original
          %%%%\TPTL@body
        \end{tablenotes}
      }%
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{ThreePartTable}
    \begin{TableNotes}[flushleft]{1}\footnotesize
\item \textbf{Table Notes:}
\item[1] textetxt.
\item[2] textetxt.
\item[3] textetxttextetxttextetxttextetxttextetxttextetx ttextetxt textetxt textetxttextetxttex tetxttextetxttextetxttextetxt textetxttextetxt textetxt.
\item[4] textetxt.
\item[5] textetxt.
\item[6] textetxt.
\item[7] textetxt.
\item[8] textetxt.
\item[9] textetxt.
\item[10] textetxt.
\item[11] textetxt.
\item[12] textetxt.
    \end{TableNotes}
    \begin{TableNotes}[flushleft]{2}\footnotesize
\item \textbf{Table Notes:}
\item[1] textetxt.
\item[8] textetxt.
\item[12] textetxt.
    \end{TableNotes}
    \begin{TableNotes}[flushleft]{3}\footnotesize
\item \textbf{Additional Notes:}
\item foo
\item bar
\item baz
    \end{TableNotes}
%
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| X || c | C | c | }
\caption{holder holder holder holder holder holder holder holder holder holder holder holder holder holder holder holder.}
\label{ProCons_CSM_DTM_SSM}                                                 \\
    \hline
                &   \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{Hooooolder}}                \\
    \cline{2-4}
\textbf{holder} &   holder  &   holder  &   holder                          \\
    \hline\hline
\endfirsthead
    \hline
                &   \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{Hooooolder}}                \\
    \cline{2-4}
\textbf{holder} &   holder  &   holder  &   holder                          \\
    \hline\hline
\endhead
    \hline
\insertTableNotes{1}\medskip\\
    \hline
\multicolumn{4}{r}{\textit{Continue on the next page}}                     \\
\endfoot
    \hline
\insertTableNotes{2}\medskip\\
    \hline
\insertTableNotes{3}\medskip\\
    \hline
\endlastfoot
% table content
holder          &   holder  &   holder  & \cellcolor{green!25} no           \\
holder & holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} no \tnote{1}  \\
    \hline
holder holder holder holder holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder\\
    \hline
\textbf{holder} & holder & holder & holder \\
    \hline
holder & holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} no \tnote{2} \\
    \hline
holder holder holder holder holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder\\
    \hline
holder & holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} no \tnote{3} \\
    \hline
holder holder holder holder holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder holder\\
    \hline
\textbf{holder} & holder & holder & holder \\
    \hline
holder & holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} no \tnote{4} \\
    \hline
holder holder holder holder holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder\\
    \hline
holder & holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} no \tnote{5} \\
    \hline
holder holder holder holder holder & holder holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder\\
    \hline
\textbf{holder} & holder & holder & holder \\
    \hline
holder & holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} no \tnote{6} \\
    \hline
holder holder holder holder holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder holder holder holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder\\
    \hline
holder & holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} no \tnote{7} \\
    \hline
holder holder holder holder holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder\\
    \hline
\textbf{holder} & holder & holder & holder \\
    \hline
holder & holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} no \tnote{8} \\
    \hline
holder holder holder holder holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder\\
    \hline
holder & holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} no \tnote{1} \\
    \hline
holder holder holder holder holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder\\
    \hline
\textbf{holder} & holder & holder & holder \\
    \hline \hline
holder & holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} no \tnote{12} \\
    \hline
holder holder holder holder holder & holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder & \cellcolor{green!25} holder\\
\end{tabularx}
    \end{ThreePartTable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. it fulfill my minimalistic expectation. however, testing it, i notice table behavior for which i didn't aware so far and for which i don't know a cause yet. to be more specific, i need to investigate more scenarios of table use. i will inform you about my findings.

Comment: problems in testing of your solution has source in my misunderstanding how works `longtable` and have not any connection with your solution.