# Page break in threeparttable with subtables

Tags: tables, page-breaking, tabularx, subcaption, threeparttable

My Table includes multiple subtables along with tablenotes at the end and they spend in two pages. I'm try to do page break and I refer to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/399937/two-pages-threeparttable-tabularx-extension), but it was a page break for footnotes only. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array, boldline}
\newcolumntype{Q}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{threeparttable}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\footnotesize
\caption{Multiple Tables with Page Break}\label{tab:LD1}
\begin{threeparttable}
\centering\addtocounter{table}{-1}%

\begin{subtable}{1\textwidth}
\caption{Table 1}\label{tab:LD1-i}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{QQQQQQQ}
\toprule
& $c=$0.15 & 0.2 & 0.3 & 0.4 & 0.5 & 0.6 \\
\cmidrule{2-7}
$d=$0.9\tnote{b} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5}  \\
0.8 & 0 & 0 & \textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5}  \\
0.7 & 0 & \textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5}  \\
0.6 & 0 & \textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5}  \\
0.5 & \textbf{0.5} &\textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5}  \\
0.4 & \textbf{0.5} &\textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5}  \\
0.3 & \textbf{0.5} &\textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5}  \\
0.2 & \textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5}  \\
0.1 & \textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5}  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{subtable}\qquad

\begin{subtable}{1\textwidth}
\caption{Table 2}\label{tab:LD1-ii}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{QQQQQQQ}
\toprule
& $c=$0.15 & 0.2 & 0.3 & 0.4 & 0.5 & 0.6 \\
\cmidrule{2-7}
$d=$0.9 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.3692 & 0.3761 & 3799  \\
0.8 & 0 & 0 &  0.3798 & 0.3866  & 0.3901  & 0.3923   \\
0.7 & 0.3732  & 0.3840 & 0.3927  & 0.3965  & 0.3986  & 0.3998   \\
0.6 & 0.3903 & 0.3957  & 0.4006  & 0.4028  & 0.4040  & 0.4048  \\
0.5 & 0.3998 & 0.4028  & \textbf{0.4056}  & \textbf{0.4070}  & \textbf{0.4077}  &     
\textbf{0.4082}  \\
0.4 & \textbf{0.4056} & \textbf{0.4074 } & \textbf{0.4090 } & \textbf{0.4098}  &     
\textbf{0.4103}  & \textbf{0.4106}   \\
0.3 & \textbf{0.4093} & \textbf{0.4103}  & \textbf{0.4112}  & \textbf{0.4117}  & 
\textbf{0.4120}  & \textbf{0.4121}   \\
0.2 & \textbf{0.4117} & \textbf{0.4122}  & \textbf{0.4127}  & \textbf{0.4129}  & 
\textbf{0.4131}  & \textbf{0.4132}   \\
0.1 & \textbf{0.4132} & \textbf{0.4134}  & \textbf{0.4136}  & \textbf{0.4137}  & 
\textbf{0.4138}  & \textbf{0.4138}   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{subtable}\qquad

\begin{subtable}{1\textwidth}
\caption{Table 3}\label{tab:LD1-iii}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{QQQQQQQ}
\toprule
& $c=$0.15 & 0.2 & 0.3 & 0.4  \\
\cmidrule{2-5}
$d=$0.9 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
0.8 & 0 & 0 &  0 & 0.2769   \\
0.7 & 0 & 0.2789  & 0.2937 & 0.2996      \\
0.6 & 0.2932 & 0.3017  & 0.3090  & 0.3122    \\
0.5 & 0.3098 & 0.3142  & 0.3183  & 0.3202   \\
0.4 & 0.3196 & 0.3220  & 0.3244  & \textbf{0.3255}  \\
0.3 & \textbf{0.3257} & \textbf{0.3270}  & \textbf{0.3283}  & \textbf{0.3290}  \\
0.2 & \textbf{0.3295} & \textbf{0.3302}  & \textbf{0.3309}  & \textbf{0.3312}  \\
0.1 & \textbf{0.3318} & \textbf{0.3321}  & \textbf{0.3324}  & \textbf{0.3326}  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{subtable}\qquad

\begin{subtable}{1\textwidth}
\caption{Table 4}\label{tab:LD1-iv}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{QQQQQQQ}
\toprule
& $c=$0.15 & 0.2 & 0.3 & 0.35  \\
\cmidrule{2-5}
$d=$0.9 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
0.8 & 0 & 0 &  0 & 0   \\
0.7 & 0 & 0  & 0.2623 & 0.2648      \\
0.6 & 0.2637 & 0.2730  & 0.2810  & 0.2823    \\
0.5 & 0.2829 & 0.2876  & 0.2919  & 0.2927   \\
0.4 & 0.2939 & 0.2965  & 0.2989  & 0.2993  \\
0.3 & 0.3007 & 0.3021  & 0.3034  & 0.3037  \\
0.2 & 0.3049 & 0.3056  & 0.3063  & 0.3064  \\
0.1 & 0.3074 & 0.3077  & 0.3081  & 0.3081  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{subtable}

\begin{subtable}{1\textwidth}
\caption{Table 4}\label{tab:LD1-iv}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{QQQQQQQ}
\toprule
& $c=$0.15 & 0.2 & 0.3 & 0.35  \\
\cmidrule{2-5}
$d=$0.9 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
0.8 & 0 & 0 &  0 & 0   \\
0.7 & 0 & 0  & 0.2623 & 0.2648      \\
0.6 & 0.2637 & 0.2730  & 0.2810  & 0.2823    \\
0.5 & 0.2829 & 0.2876  & 0.2919  & 0.2927   \\
0.4 & 0.2939 & 0.2965  & 0.2989  & 0.2993  \\
0.3 & 0.3007 & 0.3021  & 0.3034  & 0.3037  \\
0.2 & 0.3049 & 0.3056  & 0.3063  & 0.3064  \\
0.1 & 0.3074 & 0.3077  & 0.3081  & 0.3081  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{subtable}

\begin{tablenotes}
\footnotesize
\item[1] Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah 
\item[2] Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah    
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the first three tabular-like environments will fit on one page, while the final two tabular-like environments will fit on another. To address your formatting objectives, I suggest you (a) use two separate `table` environments, with a `\ContinuedFloat`  directive at the start of the second `table` environment, (b) use just one `subtable` environment per `table` environment, (c) embed the `threeparttable` environments inside the `subtable` environments, and (d) provide separate `tablenotes` environments at the end of each `threeparttable` environment. Separately, as there seems to be no need for automatic line wrapping within cells, I would also (e) switch from using `tabularx` environments to using `tabular*` environments for the five (sub)tables.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,vmargin=1in]{geometry} % set page parameters as needed
\usepackage{array,booktabs}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[table]{skip=0.5\baselineskip}
\captionsetup[subtable]{skip=0.25\baselineskip}

\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[p]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt} % let LaTeX figure out the intercolumn whitespace

\caption{Multiple Tables with Page Break}
\label{tab:LD1}

\begin{subtable}{1\textwidth}
\begin{threeparttable}

\caption{Table AA}\label{tab:LD1-i}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ccccccc}
\toprule
& $c=0.15$ & 0.2 & 0.3 & 0.4 & 0.5 & 0.6 \\
\cmidrule{2-7}
$d=0.9$\tnote{a} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5}  \\
0.8 & 0 & 0 & \textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5}  \\
0.7 & 0 & \textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5}  \\
0.6 & 0 & \textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5}  \\
0.5 & \textbf{0.5} &\textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5}  \\
0.4 & \textbf{0.5} &\textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5}  \\
0.3 & \textbf{0.5} &\textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5}  \\
0.2 & \textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5}  \\
0.1 & \textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5} & \textbf{0.5}  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\bigskip
\caption{Table BB}\label{tab:LD1-ii}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ccccccc}
\toprule
& $c=0.15$ & 0.2 & 0.3 & 0.4 & 0.5 & 0.6 \\
\cmidrule{2-7}
$d=0.9$ & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.3692 & 0.3761 & 3799  \\
0.8 & 0 & 0 &  0.3798 & 0.3866  & 0.3901  & 0.3923   \\
0.7 & 0.3732  & 0.3840 & 0.3927  & 0.3965  & 0.3986  & 0.3998   \\
0.6 & 0.3903 & 0.3957  & 0.4006  & 0.4028  & 0.4040  & 0.4048  \\
0.5 & 0.3998 & 0.4028  & \textbf{0.4056}  & \textbf{0.4070}  & \textbf{0.4077}  &     
\textbf{0.4082}  \\
0.4 & \textbf{0.4056} & \textbf{0.4074 } & \textbf{0.4090 } & \textbf{0.4098}  &     
\textbf{0.4103}  & \textbf{0.4106}   \\
0.3 & \textbf{0.4093} & \textbf{0.4103}  & \textbf{0.4112}  & \textbf{0.4117}  & 
\textbf{0.4120}  & \textbf{0.4121}   \\
0.2 & \textbf{0.4117} & \textbf{0.4122}  & \textbf{0.4127}  & \textbf{0.4129}  & 
\textbf{0.4131}  & \textbf{0.4132}   \\
0.1 & \textbf{0.4132} & \textbf{0.4134}  & \textbf{0.4136}  & \textbf{0.4137}  & 
\textbf{0.4138}  & \textbf{0.4138}   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\bigskip
\caption{Table CC}\label{tab:LD1-iii}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ccccc}
\toprule
& $c=0.15$ & 0.2 & 0.3 & 0.4  \\
\cmidrule{2-5}
$d=0.9$ & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
0.8 & 0 & 0 &  0 & 0.2769   \\
0.7 & 0 & 0.2789  & 0.2937 & 0.2996      \\
0.6 & 0.2932 & 0.3017  & 0.3090  & 0.3122    \\
0.5 & 0.3098 & 0.3142  & 0.3183  & 0.3202   \\
0.4 & 0.3196 & 0.3220  & 0.3244  & \textbf{0.3255}  \\
0.3 & \textbf{0.3257} & \textbf{0.3270}  & \textbf{0.3283}  & \textbf{0.3290}  \\
0.2 & \textbf{0.3295} & \textbf{0.3302}  & \textbf{0.3309}  & \textbf{0.3312}  \\
0.1 & \textbf{0.3318} & \textbf{0.3321}  & \textbf{0.3324}  & \textbf{0.3326}  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\bigskip
\footnotesize
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[a] Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah    
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{subtable}

\end{table}


%% allow a page break to occur

\begin{table}[p]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

\ContinuedFloat

\caption{Multiple Tables with Page Break, continued}

\begin{subtable}{1\textwidth}

\begin{threeparttable}

\caption{Table DD}\label{tab:LD1-iv}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ccccc}
\toprule
& $c=0.15$\tnote{b} & 0.2 & 0.3 & 0.35  \\
\cmidrule{2-5}
$d=0.9$ & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
0.8 & 0 & 0 &  0 & 0   \\
0.7 & 0      & 0       & 0.2623  & 0.2648  \\
0.6 & 0.2637 & 0.2730  & 0.2810  & 0.2823  \\
0.5 & 0.2829 & 0.2876  & 0.2919  & 0.2927  \\
0.4 & 0.2939 & 0.2965  & 0.2989  & 0.2993  \\
0.3 & 0.3007 & 0.3021  & 0.3034  & 0.3037  \\
0.2 & 0.3049 & 0.3056  & 0.3063  & 0.3064  \\
0.1 & 0.3074 & 0.3077  & 0.3081  & 0.3081  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\bigskip
\caption{Table EE}\label{tab:LD1-v}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ccccc}
\toprule
& $c=0.15$ & 0.2 & 0.3 & 0.35  \\
\cmidrule{2-5}
$d=0.9$ & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
0.8 & 0 & 0 &  0 & 0   \\
0.7 & 0      & 0       & 0.2623  & 0.2648  \\
0.6 & 0.2637 & 0.2730  & 0.2810  & 0.2823  \\
0.5 & 0.2829 & 0.2876  & 0.2919  & 0.2927  \\
0.4 & 0.2939 & 0.2965  & 0.2989  & 0.2993  \\
0.3 & 0.3007 & 0.3021  & 0.3034  & 0.3037  \\
0.2 & 0.3049 & 0.3056  & 0.3063  & 0.3064  \\
0.1 & 0.3074 & 0.3077  & 0.3081  & 0.3081  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\bigskip
\footnotesize
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[b] Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah    
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}

\end{subtable}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: it works great, thanks!