# Table and subtable numbering skipping

Tags: captions, numbering, threeparttable, subtables

First time posting so apologies if any mistakes/ommitted info

I have some regression tables that I am trying to put as separate subtables within a table that spans over two pages, while using \threeparttable to have notes under each portion of the tables that are separated. But as the example below shows, there are still two problems, with the numbering: (1) Table 1 is followed by Table 4 and (2) Subtable b within each table is followed by Subtable c. This was based somewhat on these solutions ([1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/689040/page-break-in-threeparttable-with-subtables)) but still not working...

Thank you, any help is much appreciated!!

```
\documentclass[a4, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{style=plaintop}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\pagestyle{plain}    

\usepackage[tablename=Table]{caption}
\DeclareCaptionTextFormat{up}{#1} % \MakeTextUppercase
\captionsetup[table]{
    labelsep=period,
    justification=centering,
    textformat=up,
}


\begin{document}

Some text, for example noting the numbers in the tables are nonsense

% First table with subtitles
\begin{table} [htp]
  \caption{Main table title}\label{tab:main}
    % \centering
    \begin{threeparttable}
    \footnotesize
    \begin{subtable}[c]{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \caption{Subtitle 1}
         \input{tables/example}
        \vspace{3mm}           
    \end{subtable}
\\  
    \begin{subtable}[c]{\textwidth}
        \centering
         \caption{Subtitle 2}
         \input{tables/example}
        \vspace{3mm}
    \end{subtable}  
    \end{threeparttable}
    \begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
    \item \scriptsize{\textit{Notes:} table notes}
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{table}

\begin{table} [htp]
\ContinuedFloat
% If possible it would be great here to have the same main table title as above but with the appended text "contd."
    \centering
    \begin{threeparttable}
    \footnotesize
    \begin{subtable}[c]{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \ContinuedFloat
         \caption{Subtitle 3}
         \input{tables/example}
        \vspace{3mm}
    \end{subtable}
\\  
    \begin{subtable}[c]{\textwidth}
        \centering
         \caption{Subtitle 4}
         \input{tables/example}
        \vspace{3mm}
    \end{subtable}  
    \end{threeparttable}
    \begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
    \item \scriptsize{\textit{Notes:} table notes}
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{table}

More text noting the numbers in the tables are the same and still nonsense

% Second table with subtitles
\begin{table} [htp]
  \caption{Main table title}\label{tab:main}
    \centering
    \begin{threeparttable}
    \footnotesize
    \begin{subtable}[c]{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \caption{Subtitle 1}
         \input{tables/example}
        \vspace{3mm}           
    \end{subtable}
\\  
    \begin{subtable}[c]{\textwidth}
        \centering
         \caption{Subtitle 2}
         \input{tables/example}
        \vspace{3mm}
    \end{subtable}  
    \end{threeparttable}
    \begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
    \item \scriptsize{\textit{Notes:} table notes}
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{table}

\begin{table} [htp]
\ContinuedFloat
% If possible it would be great here to have the same main table title as above but with the appended text "contd."
    \centering
    \begin{threeparttable}
    \footnotesize
    \begin{subtable}[c]{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \ContinuedFloat
         \caption{Subtitle 3}
         \input{tables/example}
        \vspace{3mm}
    \end{subtable}
\\  
    \begin{subtable}[c]{\textwidth}
        \centering
         \caption{Subtitle 4}
         \input{tables/example}
        \vspace{3mm}
    \end{subtable}  
    \end{threeparttable}
    \begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
    \item \scriptsize{\textit{Notes:} table notes}
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Not sure if it relevant, but I am generating my tables as a .tex in Stata then including in table using \input{}. So then example.tex looks like:

```
{
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{tabular}{l*{6}{c}}
\hline\hline
                     &\multicolumn{2}{c}{model group 1}             &\multicolumn{2}{c}{model group 2}           &\multicolumn{2}{c}{model group 3}    \\
                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(5)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(6)}         \\
\hline
Foo=1&       1.571         &       1.578         &       1.551\sym{***}&       1.177\sym{**} &      1.157         &       1.665         \\
                    &     (1.918)         &     (1.565)         &     (1.986)         &     (1.919)         &     (1.771)         &     (1.567)         \\
Goo&      -1.111         &      -1.111         &       1.119\sym{**} &       1.117         &       1.115\sym{**} &       1.116\sym{**} \\
                    &     (1.117)         &     (1.117)         &     (1.117)         &     (1.117)         &     (1.116)         &     (1.116)         \\
Foo=1 $\times$ Goo&      -1.115         &      -1.115         &      -1.111\sym{***}&      -1.111\sym{***}&      -1.117\sym{***}&      -1.118\sym{***}\\
                    &     (1.115)         &     (1.115)         &     (1.115)         &     (1.115)         &     (1.115)         &     (1.115)         \\
\hline
Some FE    &           Y         &           Y         &           Y         &           Y         &           Y         &           Y         \\
Var1       &           N         &           Y         &           N         &           Y         &           N         &           Y         \\
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{7}{l}{\footnotesize text}\\
\multicolumn{7}{l}{\footnotesize * p $<$ 1.11, ** p $<$ 1.15, *** p $<$ 1.11}\\
\end{tabular}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: It appears that threepartable is incrementing the table counter, causing the subtable counter to reset and increasing the  table number.  You don't really neeed threeparttable to effect tablenotes.

Comment: Off-topic: `a4` is not a valid option for the `article` document class. You hould probably write `a4paper`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> while using `threeparttable` to have notes under each portion of the tables that are separated

A `threeparttable` environment has three [3] formal components: (a) A `\caption` directive, (b) a `tabular`-like environment (it could also be a `tabular*` or `tabularx` environment) which may contain `\tnote` directives, and (c) a `tablenotes` environment, which is a list-like environment to show the texts associated with each `\tnote`. The main purpose of using a `threeparttable` environment is to assure that the widths of the caption and table notes do not exceed the width of the `tabular`-like environment, while allowing maximum freedom regarding the types of allowable footnote markers: They can be numeric, alphabetic (upper- and lowercase), or purely symbolic (e.g., `\dagger`). Naturally, it's up to the user (who else?) not to misuse the power afforded by the `threeparttable` machinery.

Simply put, you are *not* using the theeparttable machinery appropriately. If you really wanted to use `threeparttable` environments, they should be used *inside* the `subtable` environments.

Fortunately, the structure of your "table notes" is actually sufficiently simple so as not to require any special machinery at all. Just type

```
{\scriptsize\textit{Notes} table notes}
```

right before each instance of `\end{table}`. Do note that `\scriptsize` is a switch, i.e., it does not take an argument delimited by curly braces.

Incidentally, there's no need for more than one `\ContinuedFloat` directive per continued `table` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[tablename=Table]{caption}
\DeclareCaptionTextFormat{up}{#1} % \MakeTextUppercase
\captionsetup[table]{
    labelsep=period,
    justification=centering,
    textformat=up,
}
\usepackage{subcaption}  

\begin{document}

\noindent
Some text, for example noting the numbers in the tables are nonsense

% First table
\begin{table}[htp]
\caption{Main table title}\label{tab:main1}
\footnotesize
    \begin{subtable}{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \caption{Subtitle 1}
        %\input{tables/example11}         
    \end{subtable}
    
    \vspace{3mm}  
    \begin{subtable}{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \caption{Subtitle 2}
        %\input{tables/example12}
    \end{subtable}  

{\scriptsize\textit{Notes} table notes}
\end{table}

\begin{table} [htp]
\ContinuedFloat
\caption*{Table \thetable, continued}
\footnotesize
    \begin{subtable}{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \caption{Subtitle 3}
        %\input{tables/example13}
    \end{subtable}
    
    \vspace{3mm}  
    \begin{subtable}{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \caption{Subtitle 4}
        %\input{tables/example14}
    \end{subtable}  

{\scriptsize\textit{Notes} table notes}
\end{table}


\noindent
More text noting the numbers in the tables are the same and still nonsense

% Second table
\begin{table} [htp]
\caption{Another main table title}\label{tab:main2}
\footnotesize

    \begin{subtable}{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \caption{Subtitle 1}
        %\input{tables/example21}
    \end{subtable}
    
    \vspace{3mm}   
    \begin{subtable}{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \caption{Subtitle 2}
        %\input{tables/example22}
    \end{subtable}  

{\scriptsize\textit{Notes} table notes}
\end{table}

\begin{table} [htp!]
\ContinuedFloat
\caption*{Table \thetable, continued}
\footnotesize
    \begin{subtable}{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \caption{Subtitle 3}
        %\input{tables/example23}
    \end{subtable}
    
    \vspace{3mm} 
    \begin{subtable}{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \caption{Subtitle 4}
        %\input{tables/example24}
    \end{subtable}  

{\scriptsize\textit{Notes} table notes}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly! Only addition I needed to make, in order to have the "table notes" not centered as well but left aligned (which I did not specify requiring), was to include `\raggedright` in the line between `\end{subtable}` and `{\scriptsize\textit{Notes} table notes}`

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, I created an alternative to threeparttable which is compatible with subcaption.

TableNotes sets the margins like threeparttable, but `\Tnote` actually generates a minipage footnote (look alike).  I used `\subfloat` instead of `\subtable` as it is more of a challenge.

I also added `\Tnotemarks` to allow any desired symbols as footnote marks.  Once the list is exceeded, it reverts to arabic (offset).

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\pagestyle{plain}    

\usepackage[tablename=Table]{caption}
\DeclareCaptionTextFormat{up}{#1} % \MakeTextUppercase
\captionsetup[table]{
    labelsep=period,
    justification=centering,
    textformat=up,
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% \Tnote %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{xparse}
\makeatletter
\newsavebox{\Tnotebox}
\newcommand{\TN@Tnote}[2][0]{% #1 = count (optonal), #2 = note
  \count1=#1\relax
  \ifnum\count1=0\relax
    \footnotemark
    \global\setbox\Tnotebox=\vbox{\@parboxrestore
      \unvbox\Tnotebox
      \normalfont\footnotesize
      \makebox[\Tnotewidth][r]{\footnotemark[\c@footnote]}#2\strut}%
  \else
    \footnotemark[#1]%
    \global\setbox\Tnotebox=\vbox{\@parboxrestore
      \unvbox\Tnotebox
      \normalfont\footnotesize
      \makebox[\Tnotewidth][r]{\footnotemark[#1]}#2\strut}%
  \fi}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% \Tnotemarks %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\Tnotemax}{0}
\newcommand{\Tnotewidth}{1em}
\newcommand{\Tnotemarks}[1]% #1 = list of comma delimited symbols
{\bgroup
  \dimen0=1em
  \count1=0
  \@Tnotemarks#1,\empty,
  \xdef\Tnotemax{\number\count1}%
  \xdef\Tnotewidth{\the\dimen0}%
\egroup}
\def\quark{\quark}
\def\@Tnotemarks#1,{\ifx\empty#1\relax \else
  \advance\count1 by 1
  \settowidth{\dimen1}{\textsuperscript{#1}}%
  \ifdim\dimen1>\dimen0 \dimen0=\dimen1 \fi
  \expandafter\gdef\csname Tnotemark\number\count1\endcsname{#1}%
  \expandafter\@Tnotemarks
  \fi}
%
\newcommand{\Tnotemark}{%
  \ifnum\c@footnote>\Tnotemax\relax
    \advance\c@footnote by -\Tnotemax
    \@arabic\c@footnote
    \advance\c@footnote by \Tnotemax
  \else
    \ifnum\c@footnote>0\relax
      \csname Tnotemark\arabic{footnote}\endcsname
    \fi
  \fi}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  TableNotes %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\captiongobble}[2][]{\par}
\AtBeginDocument{\@ifundefined{subfloat}{\global\let\normalsubfloat=\relax}%
  {\global\let\normalsubfloat=\subfloat}}% for out of order packages
\NewDocumentCommand{\subfloatgobble}{oom}{\normalsubfloat{#3}}% no caption
\newcommand{\Tmarkgobble}[1][]{}% do not increment footnote counter
\newlength{\TNwidth}
%
\NewEnviron{TableNotes}[1][0pt]{% #1 = width (optional)
  \setlength{\TNwidth}{#1}%
  \ifdim\TNwidth>0pt \else
    \sbox0{\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}% measure width
      \let\Tnote=\captiongobble
      \let\Tmark=\Tmarkgobble
      \let\caption=\captiongobble
      \let\subfloat=\subfloatgobble
      \let\label=\@gobble
      \BODY
    \end{varwidth}}%
    \TNwidth=\wd0
  \fi
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}{\TNwidth}
    \let\Tnote=\TN@Tnote
    \let\Tmark=\footnotemark
    \let\thefootnote=\Tnotemark
    \BODY
    \par\vskip\skip\@mpfootins
    \footnoterule
    \unvbox\Tnotebox
  \end{minipage}\par
}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\Tnotemarks{*,**}

\begin{table} [htp]
\begin{TableNotes}
  \caption{Main table title}\label{tab:main}
    \centering
    \subfloat[]{\begin{tabular}{c}
      \hline
      This is a test\Tnote{Footnote 1}\\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}}        
 
    \subfloat[]{\begin{tabular}{c}
      \hline
      This is a test\Tnote{Footnote 2}\\
      This is a repeat\Tmark[1]\\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}}
\end{TableNotes}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: "Frankly, I always thought they could have done a better job." Well, I would *not* blame the author(s) of the `threeparttable` package for a case of complete and utter misuse of the package's machinery. It's sort of like blaming Ferrari (the company) for a testarossa driver not obeying a town's posted speed limit...

Comment: @Mico - I meant they could have actually implemented footnotes instead of using separate `\tfoot` (footnote marks) and an itemized list.  It would take an environ if you don't know the width.

Comment: The beauty of `threeparttable` is that it lets users employ numeric, alphabetic, and symbolic footnote markers all at once, in one and the same `tabular`-like environment. Natuarally, it's up to the user not to abuse this power. Of course, the OP doesn't appear to use any `\tnote` directives at all, begging the question as to why they employ a `threeparttable` to begin with.