How to remove extra column at the end of the table
I want to have a 4 column table using package \usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}. The table is based on the codes below.
\begin{table} [h]
    \caption{Main results after endogeneity correction}
    \label{tab:main_results_endog}
    \centering
    \SingleSpacedXI
    \begin{subtable}[c]{\textwidth}
    \caption{Cost analysis \label{tbl:main_results_cost}}
        \centering
        \begin{threeparttable}
            
        \begin{tabular}{p{0.35\textwidth}lcp{0.35\textwidth}lcp{0.35\textwidth}lcp{0.35\textwidth}c}
          \hline\hline 
          
                    &   MRO &   Repair & Maintenance    \\  \hline
        $XXX$   &   $-0.070^{***}$ & $-0.098^{***}$ &  XXX  \\  
                &      (0.0032)          &    (0.0033)   &  XXX    \\
        Car attributes controls &   Yes & Yes   &   Yes \\  
        Driver attributes controls  &   Yes & Yes  & Yes    \\  
        $R^2$   &   0.286 & 0.296   &   XXX \\  
        \# Observations &   19,410,026 & 19,410,026     &   XXX \\  \hline\hline 
         \end{tabular}
          \begin{tablenotes}
              \item Note: Standard errors in parentheses (* p $<$ 0.05, ** p $<$ 0.01, *** p $<$ 0.001)
          \end{tablenotes}
         \end{threeparttable}
  \end{subtable}       
\quad%  
   \begin{subtable}[c]{\textwidth}
    \caption{Frequency analysis \label{tbl:main_results_frequency}}
        \centering
        \begin{threeparttable}
        \begin{tabular}{p{0.35\textwidth}lcp{0.35\textwidth}lcp{0.35\textwidth}lcp{0.35\textwidth}c}
          \hline\hline 
          
                    &   MRO &   Repair & Maintenance    \\  \hline
        $XXX$   &   $0.055^{***}$ & $0.052^{***}$   & XXX   \\  
                &      (0.0025)          &    (0.0025)   & XXX    \\
        Car attributes controls     &   Yes & Yes   & Yes   \\  
        Driver attributes controls  &   Yes & Yes & Yes \\  
        $R^2$   &   0.266 & 0.286   & XXX   \\  
        \# Observations &   18,522,387 & 18,522,387  & XXXX     \\  \hline\hline 
         \end{tabular}
         \begin{tablenotes}
              \item Note: Standard errors in parentheses (* p $<$ 0.05, ** p $<$ 0.01, *** p $<$ 0.001)
          \end{tablenotes}
        \end{threeparttable}
    \end{subtable}
\end{table}


The codes output the table below. Why is there extra column in the end? How shall I remove it?


How or where is \SingleSpacedXI defined?

See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/277901/remove-specific-column-from-multiple-tables and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/714331/table-and-subtable-numbering-skipping/714337?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C0.0000#714337

You're currently specifying both tabular environments to have 11 [!] columns. Since both tables actually have only 4 columns, the best way to fix the formatting issue is to change both instances of
\begin{tabular}{p{0.35\textwidth}lcp{0.35\textwidth}lcp{0.35\textwidth}lcp{0.35\textwidth}c}

to
\begin{tabular}{p{0.35\textwidth}lcp{0.35\textwidth}}

This assumes, of course, that you're fine with the specifications of the four remaining columns. If you're not, feel free to come up with better choices.
Three additional comments:

Since you're barely making use of the machinery of the threeparttable package, I'd avoid incurring its overhead.

To simplify the job of assuring that the tables will fit inside the text block, I'd switch from tabular to tabularx environments (with target widths of \textwidth) and replace the second instance of p{0.35\textwidth} with X.

I'd get rid of the busy-looking \hline\hline directives and replace them with the rule-drawing macros of the booktabs package: \toprule, \midrule, and \bottomrule.



\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{subcaption,booktabs,tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \caption{Main results after endogeneity correction}
    \label{tab:main_results_endog}
    
    % \SingleSpacedXI % huh?
    

    \begin{subtable}{\textwidth}

    \caption{Cost analysis}
    \label{tbl:main_results_cost}
       
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} p{0.35\textwidth} l c X @{}}
        \toprule       
                    &   MRO &   Repair & Maintenance    \\  
        \midrule
        \textit{XXX}   &   $-0.070^{***}$ & $-0.098^{***}$ &  XXX  \\  
                       &      (0.0032)    &    (0.0033)    &  XXX    \\
        \addlinespace
        Car attributes controls     &   Yes & Yes   &   Yes \\  
        Driver attributes controls  &   Yes & Yes  & Yes    \\  
        $R^2$                       &   0.286 & 0.296   &   XXX \\  
        \# Observations             &   19,410,026 & 19,410,026     &   XXX \\  
        \bottomrule 
    \end{tabularx}
         
    \smallskip\footnotesize
    Note: Standard errors in parentheses; $^{*}$ $p < 0.05$, $^{**}$ $p < 0.01$, $^{***}$ $p < 0.001$.
    \end{subtable}       

    \bigskip\bigskip
    \begin{subtable}{\textwidth}

    \caption{Frequency analysis} 
    \label{tbl:main_results_frequency}

    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} p{0.35\textwidth} l c X @{}}
        \toprule      
                    &   MRO &   Repair & Maintenance    \\  
        \midrule
        \textit{XXX}   &   $0.055^{***}$ & $0.052^{***}$   & XXX   \\  
                       &      (0.0025)   &    (0.0025)   & XXX    \\
        \addlinespace
        Car attributes controls     &   Yes & Yes   & Yes   \\  
        Driver attributes controls  &   Yes & Yes & Yes \\  
        $R^2$                       &   0.266 & 0.286   & XXX   \\  
        \# Observations             &   18,522,387 & 18,522,387  & XXXX     \\  
        \bottomrule 
    \end{tabularx}
        
    \smallskip\footnotesize
    Note: Standard errors in parentheses; $^{*}$ $p < 0.05$, $^{**}$ $p < 0.01$, $^{***}$ $p < 0.001$.
\end{subtable}
\end{table}

\end{document}

